# Aurelia not injecting on library class

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, aurelia

I'm playing with the Aurelia intro tutorial and changing it to make a rest call from a custom class.  In my class I'm getting an 'http is undefined' error with my method calls, so it appears that Aurelia services aren't being injected.  Does injecting work if Aurelia isn't loading the class module?

**home.js:**

```
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css!';
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css!';
import 'styles/style.css!'
import 'bootstrap';
import {Search} from '../lib/search.js';

export class Home {

  heading = 'Welcome to Aurelia!';
  firstName = 'John';
  lastName = 'Doe';

  activate() {
  }

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  submit() {
    var s = new Search();
    s.fetch()
      .then(results => this.results = results);
  }

}
```

**search.js:**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Search {

  constructor(http) {
    // constructor is called but http is undefined
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration();
    });

    this.http = http;
  }

  fetch() {
    // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    return this.http.fetch('find')
      .then(response => response.json());
  }

}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: http is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Search` has to be injected in `Home` and better not to use `.js` when importing

```
import {Search} from '../lib/search';
@inject(Search)
export class Home {
  constructor(search) {

  }
}
```

UPD: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34796010/3436921 you can find more examples on different ways of using injection

UPD2: Or you can pass `HttpClient` instance manually to the `Search` constructor

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
@inject(HttpClient)
export class Home {
 constructor(http) {
   this.http = http;
 }
 ...
 submit() {
  var s = new Search(this.http);
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Although this answer solves my error, it doesn't answer my question on why injection of `HttpClient` on the `Search` class doesn't work. Can you explain?

Comment: when you create `new Search()`, injections inside `Search` are not executed, because injection should be parsed by aurelia engine. To get `HttpClient ` inside `Search` just inject it in `Home` and then pass it to Search `new Search(this.http)`